# How to use npm-gcm in meteorjs app

Tags: meteor, push-notification, npm, google-cloud-messaging

Please I'm totally at lost on how to use npm-gcm for push notification in my meteor js app for android. I tried to use 'meteor add meteorhacks:npm' but I kept getting the following error report:

```
W20160211-20:10:53.951(1)? (STDERR)           
W20160211-20:10:53.952(1)? (STDERR)   /Users/bbgg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20160211-20:10:53.952(1)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20160211-20:10:53.953(1)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20160211-20:10:53.953(1)? (STDERR) Error: Can't find npm module 'node-gcm'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'npm-container' package?
W20160211-20:10:53.953(1)? (STDERR)     at Object.Npm.require (/Users/bbgg/GoodDay/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:175:17)
W20160211-20:10:53.953(1)? (STDERR)     at Object.Meteor.npmRequire (packages/npm-container/index.js:2:1)
W20160211-20:10:53.953(1)? (STDERR)     at server/app.js:2:22
W20160211-20:10:53.954(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/bbgg/GoodDay/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/server/app.js:45:4
W20160211-20:10:53.954(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/bbgg/GoodDay/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
W20160211-20:10:53.954(1)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160211-20:10:53.954(1)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/bbgg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20160211-20:10:53.954(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/bbgg/GoodDay/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20160211-20:11:07.823(1)? (STDERR)           
W20160211-20:11:07.824(1)? (STDERR) /Users/bbgg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20160211-20:11:07.824(1)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20160211-20:11:07.824(1)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20160211-20:11:07.830(1)? (STDERR) Error: Can't find npm module 'node-gcm'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'npm-container' package?
W20160211-20:11:07.830(1)? (STDERR)     at Object.Npm.require (/Users/bbgg/GoodDay/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:175:17)
W20160211-20:11:07.831(1)? (STDERR)     at Object.Meteor.npmRequire (packages/npm-container/index.js:2:1)
W20160211-20:11:07.831(1)? (STDERR)     at server/app.js:2:22
W20160211-20:11:07.831(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/bbgg/GoodDay/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/server/app.js:45:4
W20160211-20:11:07.831(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/bbgg/GoodDay/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
W20160211-20:11:07.831(1)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160211-20:11:07.831(1)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/bbgg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20160211-20:11:07.831(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/bbgg/GoodDay/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20160211-20:11:20.323(1)? (STDERR)           
W20160211-20:11:20.324(1)? (STDERR) /Users/bbgg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20160211-20:11:20.324(1)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20160211-20:11:20.324(1)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20160211-20:11:20.331(1)? (STDERR) Error: Can't find npm module 'node-gcm'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'npm-container' package?
W20160211-20:11:20.331(1)? (STDERR)     at Object.Npm.require (/Users/bbgg/GoodDay/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:175:17)
W20160211-20:11:20.331(1)? (STDERR)     at Object.Meteor.npmRequire (packages/npm-container/index.js:2:1)
W20160211-20:11:20.331(1)? (STDERR)     at server/app.js:2:22
W20160211-20:11:20.331(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/bbgg/GoodDay/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/server/app.js:45:4
W20160211-20:11:20.332(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/bbgg/GoodDay/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
W20160211-20:11:20.332(1)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160211-20:11:20.332(1)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/bbgg/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20160211-20:11:20.332(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/bbgg/GoodDay/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a dedicated meteor package rather than a homebrew implementation of GCM direct, this package from Raix is really good and easy to use and covers both push messaging for mobile apps and for chrome etc: https://github.com/raix/push

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, one thing is not clear about instruction contained there is how to install the raix push in meteor app. I intended to download and it from github, unzip it and copy paste it into meteor project folder. Please let me know if it should not be done that way. Thanks in anticipation to your help.

Comment: It is in the meteor atmosphere repository so you can just use meteor add raix:push in your console to add the package. Docs on github should help with the rest of the set up